# Windows 11 WSL2 - ZSH permission denied after brew install

Tags: homebrew, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to set up a new PC with some development tools, but am running into `zsh` permission problems when trying to run the application.

**TL;DR** how do I give `zsh` the required permissions to run an application installed by `brew`?

I'm running:

- Windows 11 with WSL2.
- ZSH shell
- Homebrew (for installations)

As you see in the screenshot, I can install an application successfully with `brew`, but when I try to open/run the application in a `zsh` shell, I get `zsh: permission denied`.

Admittedly all this stuff confused the hell out of me, so I'm hoping people who know this kinda stuff can save me which a quick command I need to run. Thanks!

[image: brew-install-zsh-denied]